# Best approach to convert a MySQL procedure to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following script but unable to migrate using SQL Server migration for MySQL.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [usp_contacts_delete]
(_contactid int)
BEGIN
DELETE
FROM    dbo.rivereast_contacts
WHERE   contactid = _contactid
;
END
```

Which software can I use to migrate it, if not how can I manually change it to create a spx for SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shouldn't be hard:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_contacts_delete (
    @contactid int
) AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM dbo.rivereast_contacts
    WHERE contactid = @contactid;
END;
```